# SQL: Split rows out of values from multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

| ID | State Name | State Value | City Name | City Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Indiana | 8.0 | Gary | 5.0 |
| 2 | Florida | 9.0 | Miami | 2.0 |

I would like to output a table that looks something like this:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | State, Indiana | 8.0 |
| 2 | City, Gary | 5.0 |
| 3 | State, Florida | 9.0 |
| 4 | City, Miami | 2.0 |

I was trying to solve by groupby but that is just outputting unique rows in their entirety not creating unique rows based off multiple columns unique values.

Comment: Can you write a query to *just* handle the states?  And another to *just* handle the cities?  Then just `union` them together.

Comment: Ah yes good call that did what I want. Sorry it's always the simple answers I overlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select concat('State, ', StateName) as Name, StateValue as Value
from table_name
union all
select concat('City, ', CityName) as Name, CityValue as Value
from table_name;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you concat `'City, '` to `CityName`?